# Tryin to add an instance method to my Hashmap which takes two arguments representing a key and a value

Tags: java, hashmap

I am writing a hashmap in which I am trying to add a method `addMapEntry()` which Takes two arguments representing a key and a value. Adds the key and value to the map. If the key is already present the existing value is overwritten. Returns no value.

Note that the map values are collections, so the second argument must be of an `appropriatecollection` type.

here is my code so far and what I have tried:

```
        }
        public void addMapEntry(String recipekey, Set<String> values){
              recipes.(key,values);

        }
    }
```

Comment: ```recipes.(key,values);``` ? Which method do you intend to use? What have you tried?

Comment: well I have tried the above for what I am trying to do but its not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void addMapEntry(String recipekey, Set<String> values){
          recipes.(key,values);

 }
```

should probably be

```
 public void addMapEntry(String recipekey, Set<String> values){
          recipes.put(recipekey,values);

 }
```

I recommend using some sort of IDE with syntax highlighting ;)

Comment: so when i try that it says cannot find variable key

Comment: um well obviously it is recipes.put(recipekey, values); ^^

Comment: did you try recipekey instead of key? what is the error?

Comment: oh yes that worked! thanks so i just missed out recipe wow! thanks